# Unable to get the id in ExposedDropDownMenu ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, spinner

I was able to display a list if single element, but I also want to get the corresponding ID of the selected element in the dropdown.

```
data class ChannelCategory(
val channelCategory: String,
val channelCategory_InternalId: String )

private fun channelCategoryDropDown(it: List<ChannelCategory>){
    val values = ArrayList<String>()

for (x in it){
        values.add(x.channelCategory)
    }
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(), R.layout.add_cutomer_list_items, values)
customerChannelCategory.setAdapter(adapter) }
```

Is there a way to get the corresponding "channelCategory_InternalId" when clicked ex: "Wholesaler"?

below image is the result if I use the below code

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(), R.layout.add_cutomer_list_items, it)
```

[image]

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? How to display a certain `String` in the dropdown items? Or how to get that `String` when an item is clicked?

Comment: I was able to get the name and display list of string in the exposed dropdown (channelCategory), but when I clicked I want to get the (channelCategory_InternalId)

Comment: Are you asking how to set an `OnItemSelectedListener` on a `Spinner`? Or how to get the selected `ChannelCategory` there?

Comment: Its not a spinner, it is exposeddropdownmenu.

Comment: `ExposedDropdownMenu` is not a `View`. It's a type of style that you can set on a `TextInputLayout`. There has to be something else inside the `TextInputLayout` – e.g., a `Spinner`, some subclass thereof, etc. – because `TextInputLayout` does not have its own dropdown, and it does not take an `ArrayAdapter`, like you're setting on `customerChannelCategory`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the my answer, getting the ID of the list of exposeddropdown menu using the onclicklistener overriding OnItemClick()

```
channelCategoryId.value = it[position].channelCategory_InternalId
```